# Wordpress scroll to anchor with custom pages doesn't work properly

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm begginer and creating Wordpress website from scratch. I have a problem with page scroll to anchor, if it is single page - scroll is working with `#service`, but if my website is with home page where I need the scroll and custom pages where i do not, and I need get back from custom page to my home page with same menu buttons and to the content which button is pressed. How should I fix it?

I hope you understand me and thanks in advice :)

There is my code and photos:

```
//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var $anchor_scroll = $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top;
        var $anchor_scroll_calc = $anchor_scroll;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $anchor_scroll_calc
        }, 1500);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My header menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">
                  <img id="#page-top" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo3.png" alt="Brand logo">
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php
              wp_nav_menu( array(
                  'menu'              => 'primary',
                  'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                  'depth'             => 0,
                  'container'         => 'div',
                  'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse',
                  'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                  'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                  'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                  'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
              );
          ?>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

And wordpress photos to see what I mean: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: The custom URL is assuming you're visiting another website - which your menu won't exist on (unless it's opening in an iframe). You can't "scrollto" an external website.

Comment: What should I do then?